# OS X stopped auto mounting external drivers

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, mount

My MacBook stopped auto-mounting external hard drives this week.  I have to mount them in Disk Utility, which works fine.

This has happened with three different drives (which all had Time Machine volumes). Flash drives still auto-mount, as did an SSD.

I think this may or may not have coincided with installing Parallels Desktop, but I haven't been running it, even in the background.

This is a 2016 USB-C MacBook Pro running 10.14.4.

Comment: How are these drives formatted? APFS, HFS+, FAT32, …? Are they encrypted?

Comment: @GrahamMiln Encrypted HFS+ Time Machine volumes.

Answer (score 1):

## Encrypted Core Storage and macOS 10.14.4

macOS 10.14.4 changed the behaviour of auto-mounting Core Storage/HFS+ formatted encrypted drives. These drives appear to no longer be automatically mounted.

Please [let Apple know](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) this change of behaviour in a minor macOS update is causing you problems. The more people who provide feedback, the better and the better the chance of it being assigned engineering time.

See [Automatically Mount Encrypted Core Storage Volume (10.14.4+)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356931/automatically-mount-encrypted-core-storage-volume-10-14-4).

Comment: Interesting - I don't have any encrypted external drives, so have never noticed this phenomenon.